# Wildcard on multiple columns in Elastic search query

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

I have a requirement to match an input passed by user across 2 attributes in elastic search and it needs to be a wildcard search.

I am using AWS-ES version 6.4

When I query on one single attribute the results are okay but when I include both the attributes, it gives me 400 status code.

**Query which works:**

```
 {"query": 
{"bool": {"should": [  
{"wildcard": { "phone1.searchTerm": "*1234*" }} 
]}}
}
```

**Query which fails:** (phone1 and phone2 both)
Is there a binding on should/must condition to have only one wildcard inside it?

```
{"query": 
{"bool": {"should": [  
{"wildcard": { "phone1.searchTerm": "*1234*" }}    ,
{"wildcard": { "phone2.searchTerm": "*1234*" }}    ]}}
}
```

Does this have something to do with elastic search version?

Comment: can you add the complete error message with the error 400 ?

Comment: The error was due to mapping issue, searchTerm in phone2 was defined as long. Checking the error properly helped me to identify that.

Answer (score 0):

it will work as follows :-

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "Author": "roh*"
                }
            },
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "Title": "q*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```